# More complicated goals in higher order Prolog

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, prolog, higher-order-functions

Let me give a concrete example to explain my question:

> Given a list of lists `LoL` and a list `Ex`, construct `X` that contains all elements (sublists) of `LoL` after subtracting `Ex` from them.

Just to give you an example:

```
?- my_exclude([[1, 2, 3], [1], [3, 4]], [2, 3], X).
X = [[1], [1], [4]].
```

I know that I could use `subtract/3` from the `lists` library, but I can’t figure out how to implement this kind of mapping.

I know `maplist`, but I don’t see how I could make use of that here.

What I am probably missing is some kind of `map` predicate that would transform `LoL` into `X` while applyling an operation to each element, that operation being the subtraction of `Ex`.

**How could I go about doing this, without resorting to ‘manually’ implementing this on a lower level, recursively?**

*(In other words, maybe I am looking for lambdas, that don’t seem to exist in standard Prolog)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `subtract(Li, [2,3], Ri)` for each `Li` in the list `L` to produce a result `Ri` in the result list `R`.

You can make use of a *lambda expression* with:

```
my_exclude(L, E, R) :-
    maplist({E}/[Li, Ri]>>subtract(Li, E, Ri), L, R).
```

Here `{E}/[Li, Ri]>>subtract(Li, E, Ri)` is thus a goal with two variables `Li` and `Ri` that will, when called, call `subtract(Li, E, Ri)` where `E` is the list of elements we want to exclude.

Comment: Thank you for fixing my horrible phrasing and explaining the problem clearly. I have seen this kind of lambda expression before – is it standard? I am coding with SWI prolog, but the code has to run in SICStus as well.

Comment: @bp99: it is part of the *yall* library: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3E%3E)/2 You can thus import this library if this is not done implicitly in SICStus Prolog.

Comment: @bp99 This is Logtalk lambda expression syntax (which makes it available for all supported backend systems, including SICStus Prolog). It's also available in SWI-Prolog using `library(yall)`.

Comment: This is amazing, this syntax seems to be extremely useful. Thanks.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It should be `{E}/[Li, Ri]>>subtract(Li, E, Ri)`. All variables in a lambda expression should be declared as either free variables or as lambda parameters.